# simple Clock in python

Tags: python

I wanted to program a simple clock in python:

```
class Clock:
    def __init__(self):
        self._hours = 0
        self._minutes = 0

    def gethours(self):
        return self._hours

    def getminutes(self):
        return self._minutes

    def sethours(self, hours):
        self._hours = hours

    def setminutes(self,minutes):
        if self._minutes > 60:
            self._hours = self._hours + 1
            self._minutes = 1
        else:
            self._minutes = minutes

    def tic(self):
        if self._minutes > 58:
            self._hours = self._hours + 1
            self._minutes = 1
        else:
            self._minutes = self._minutes + 1

    minutes = property(getminutes, setminutes)
    hours = property(gethours, sethours)
```

But when I now wanted to check it with the following code I get an AssertionError at `assert(c.hours == i and c.minutes == j)`

```
c = Clock()

assert(c.minutes == 0 and c.hours == 0)

for i in range(24):
    assert(c.hours == i)
    for j in range(60):
        assert(c.hours == i and c.minutes == j)
        c.tic()

assert(c.minutes == 0 and c.hours == 0)
```

Comment: `for` each `i` and `j` you execute the `assert` operation. `c.hours` can't equal with all values that `i` will get, just as `c.minutes` won't equall all the values that `j` will get

Comment: At minute 59, you add 1 to the hours and put minutes back to 1. Shouldn't it be 0 minutes by then?

Comment: @HeadhunterXamd OP already said he gets the `AssertionError` on this line: `assert(c.hours == i and c.minutes == j)`

Comment: @Adelin I just saw that whoops, removed it, and reposted it with an explanation.

Comment: @Ambriador It is because the c.minutes variable never becomes 0, the loop goes from 0...59( 60 if it is inclusive, I don't remember if the python range function is inclusive) while the c.minutes minimum value will be 1 because of the tic function.

Comment: All `set*` methods are never used, but if they are to be used at some point, they also should be corrected (minimum number of minutes being 0, not 1). Actually, when you `tic()` you should use the setters instead of rewriting what they contain. Like correct the minutes setter and use `def tic(): self.minutes += 1`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fixed rewriting, using the same test.
The setters take care of setting correctly the values for hours and minutes (though hours' setter does not manage correctly adding more than one day, but this is easy to add based on the same model as for minutes).

Then `tic()` is only a shortcut for adding one minute.

Comment out the `print` statement to remove all hours:minutes.

Note: I've turned `Clock` to a "new style" class object, that allow to use property decorators and makes everything more readable (this not necessary for python3, but necessary to let the same code work also in python2).

```
class Clock(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._hours = 0
        self._minutes = 0

    @property
    def hours(self):
        return self._hours

    @property
    def minutes(self):
        return self._minutes

    @minutes.setter
    def minutes(self, value):
        if value >= 60:
            # Take care, if one adds more than one hour, to
            # take the extra hours into account too:
            self.hours += value // 60
        self._minutes = value % 60

    @hours.setter
    def hours(self, value):
        self._hours = value % 24

    def tic(self):
        self.minutes += 1


c = Clock()

assert(c.minutes == 0 and c.hours == 0)

for i in range(24):
    assert(c.hours == i)
    for j in range(60):
        assert(c.hours == i and c.minutes == j)
        c.tic()
        print('{}:{}'.format(c.hours, c.minutes))

assert(c.minutes == 0 and c.hours == 0)
```

Excerpt and end of output:

```
12:57
12:58
12:59
13:0
13:1
13:2
13:3
.
.
.
23:46
23:47
23:48
23:49
23:50
23:51
23:52
23:53
23:54
23:55
23:56
23:57
23:58
23:59
0:0
```